# What is the probability of selecting 2 balls from a bag of $n$ blue balls and $m$ red balls, if...

Tags: probability

Say there are $n$ blue balls and $m$ red balls in a bag.
What is the probability of selecting 2 balls if exactly 1 is red and the other is blue?

**Note:**
If these balls are selected at the same time (i.e. I put my hand in the bag and pull out two balls simultaneous), will the probability be the same as if I selected them separately? (i.e. I put my hand in the bag and pull out one, then put my hand in again and pull out the second one.)

---

From trying with a few values of $n$ and $m$, it appears the probability is the same in both cases, which is a bit surprising. $ $  Any clarification would be great.

Comment: I had even removed that comment almost immediately after writing it because I felt it imprecisely worded and unsatisfying., but another attempt at phrasing it, the outcomes in the sample space where selections are made simultaneously correspond uniquely with pairs of outcomes in the sample space where selections are made separately.  In both sample spaces, events such as "one red and one blue were drawn" have essentially the same representation, either as the collections of individual outcomes or as the collections of the associated pairs of outcomes, and thus the same probability.

Comment: Are you sure you stated the right problem? You really want the probability of "selecting two balls", not the probability of "selecting one red ball and one blue ball, given that you select two balls"?

Comment: @bof Yes, it's the correct problem.  The problem specifically, stated ''at the same time'', which made me consider what would it be if it wasn't at the same time.  Apparently, nothing chances.  Pointless confusion..

Comment: @bof I think you may be taking the problem as written a bit *too* literally.  "what is the probability that given that I pulled out exactly one red and exactly one blue that I pulled out two balls", the answer is of course $100\%$.  This is not an interesting question however.  The problem intended and how I read it originally was "Given that you draw two balls (*simultaneously or in sequence*) what is the probability that exactly one is red and the other is blue?"

Comment: @JMoravitz I think this repository of questions and answers will be more useful to future users if the questions are formulated so that they can be read literally. I don't think it's useful to be answering questions without first getting the questions stated correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Think about the size of the configuation space in each case. When you choose two balls from $n+m$ balls there are $T_{n+m}=(n+m)(n+m-1)/2$ ways. So the probabilites are
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(\color{blue}{BB}) = \frac{ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}} { \frac{(n+m)(n+m-1)}{2}} =\color{blue}{\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+m)(n+m-1)}} \\
P(\color{blue}{B}\color{red}{R} \text{ or } \color{red}{R}\color{blue}{B}) =\frac{2\color{blue}{n}\color{red}{m}}{(\color{blue}{n}+\color{red}{m})(\color{blue}{n}+\color{red}{m}-1)} \\
P(\color{red}{RR}) = \color{red}{\frac{m(m-1)}{(n+m)(n+m-1)}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now do the calculation by choosing the first ball , followed by the second ball ( without replacement) and observe that you do indeed obtain the same result.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I think you missed a minus sign on the second line.  $(n+m+1)$ should be $(n+m-1)$.